# How to bind an object with keys and values in Angular?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

In Typescript I receive `data` from ASP.NET Core C# `Dictionary` (It is not a `Map` but it has keys and values ie I can run `Object.keys(data)` and `Object.values(data)`).

In HTML I have an Angular component which binds to `data`. I cant figure out the syntax for binding the key and values array.

Roughly:

```
      <dx-gallery [dataSource]="data">
        <div *dxTemplate="let i of 'item'">
          <dx-chart [dataSource]="i.value">
            <dxi-series [name]="i.key" valueField="value.X"
```

*`i` is a single key value pair (a string and an array) from whole data collection. in C# I would write `i.Key` and `i.Value` but it doesnt work in Typescript for me (the component doesnt see data to display).*

**I need to bind `key` and `X`**

*the data is {A: Array, B: Array} where Array is MyObj[]*

Comment: Can you clarify a bit for us? What is the output of `data`. e.g. if you bind it to the dom via `<pre>{{data | json}}</pre>`. Also, `let i of 'item'` seems like it will just iterate over the chars in the string 'item'. Or at least share the function behind the *dxTemplate input.

Comment: data is bunch of key-value pairs and i is each of the pairs. its in the text.

Comment: how is this not SO question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the native `KeyValuePipe` from Angular: [here](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

It would look like this, and allow you to refer to the entries with `key` and `value`:

```html
<dx-gallery [dataSource]="data">
  <div *dxTemplate="let i of item | keyvalue">
     <dx-chart [dataSource]="i.value">
       <dxi-series [name]="i.key" valueField="value.X">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can loop over an object, by grabbing it's keys.

e.g.

```
// component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  data = {
    prop1: 'a',
    prop2: 'b'
  };
  keys = Object.keys(this.data);
}
```

--

```
//component.html
<p *ngFor="let k of keys">
  {{k}} : {{data[k]}}
</p>
```

Alternatively, you can expose the `Object` class to the html template and grab the keys and values as needed.

e.g.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  data = {
    prop1: 'a',
    prop2: 'b'
  };
  keys = Object.keys(this.data);
  Object = Object;
}
```

--

```
// html
<p *ngFor="let k of Object.keys(data)">
  {{k}} : {{data[k]}}
</p>
```

However, adding function calls to your html can sometimes be less performant than just storing the the var "keys" in the `ts` file, as the function will reevaluate with every change detection cycle.

Comment: I cant use ngFor because `dx-gallery` provides same functionality already and it has its purpose I cant rid off of it

Comment: its a slider which displays multiple items one by one

Comment: maybe there is some help in the [docs](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxGallery/Configuration/#dataSource)
Sorry, I don't know much about that library, but good luck, seems like there could be some helpful info. Looks like `[dataSource]`  requires an imput of an array, not an object "Assign the array to the dataSource option."

Comment: I think typescript/js simply dont have what i want and i am going to use function approach as you suggested.

Comment: looks like you may just need to transform your object into an array before you send it into the [dataSource] input.

Comment: yes it works like that right now.. but then how do I get `key` into the name of each chart :) thats the problem. JS just not cut for this.. It was made up out of thin air in 1995..